# Extracting attribute from XML that can be at random places using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am just a begginer with XML/XSL and been given a file to extract the used AudioFiles from.

The XML contains on many places the ATTRIBUTE named AudioFile and the contents is a wave file name like request_welcome.wav. The attributes can be anywhere in the file and all I need is a list of the names of the wave files

The Attribute is `<ATTRIBUTE NAME="AudioFile"><VALUE>hold.wav</VALUE></ATTRIBUTE>` and can be anywhere in the XML

I used:

```
`<xsl:for-each select="ENTRY">
   <xsl:for-each select="ATTRIBUTE">
     <xsl:if test="@NAME='AudioFile'">
       <xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>`
```

It however doesn't return all values I'm majorly out of my knowledge zone and looked at examples from the web and tried to implement them but not with the expected result.

Any suggestions as to how to approach this are appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that the element `<ATTRIBUTE>` can be anywhere in the XML, I am guessing the input XML would be something like

```
<ENTRY>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME="AudioFile">
        <VALUE>hold.wav</VALUE>
    </ATTRIBUTE>
    <NODE1>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME="AudioFile">
            <VALUE>hold1.wav</VALUE>
        </ATTRIBUTE>
        <NODE2>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="AudioFile">
                <VALUE>hold2.wav</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
        </NODE2>
    </NODE1>
    <NODE3>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME="AudioFile">
            <VALUE>hold4.wav</VALUE>
        </ATTRIBUTE>
    </NODE3>
</ENTRY>
```

If you are looking to output the value of `ATTRIBUTE/VALUE` you can use the template approach instead of using `for-each`. The below template would output the values.

```
<xsl:template match="ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = 'AudioFile']">
    <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="VALUE" />
    </Name>
</xsl:template>
```

In case you need to use a `for-each`, it needs to be coded using `//` which would look for all `<ATTRIBUTE>` elements in the XML irrespective of their location.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = 'AudioFile']" >
```

However the template approach is preferred since XSLT is designed to work on templates.

The output would be

```
<Name>hold.wav</Name>
<Name>hold1.wav</Name>
<Name>hold2.wav</Name>
<Name>hold4.wav</Name>
```